# Is $(x^n - y^n) = (x-y)(\sum\limits_{i=0}^{n-1}x^{n-1-i}y^i)$ for integer $n$ when $x,y$ are real?

Tags: summation, solution-verification, real-numbers, integers

It seems to me that this should hold for all real $x,y$ as long as $n$ is an integer since:

$$x\left(\sum\limits_{i=0}^{n-1}x^{n-1-i}y^i\right) = \sum\limits_{i=0}^{n-1}x^{n-i}y^i$$
$$y\left(\sum\limits_{i=0}^{n-1}x^{n-1-i}y^i\right) = \sum\limits_{i=0}^{n-1}x^{n-1-i}y^{i+1}$$
$$(x-y)\left(\sum\limits_{i=0}^{n-1}x^{n-1-i}y^i\right) = x^n + \left(x^{n-1}y - x^{n-1}y\right) + \dots + \left(xy^{n-1} - xy^{n-1}\right) - y^n$$

Am I wrong?

Comment: Try induction...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your reasoning works for $n\ge1$.

The case $n=0$ also works, but has a subtlety: we need the combinatorial convention $x^0=1$ (even if $x=0$), and $\sum_{i=0}^{-1}$ gives an "empty" sum of $0$.

It doesn't work for negative integers $n$, since then $\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}$ should still give an empty sum.

Comment: Thanks! Yes, I forgot about non-positive $n$.